# Redux state won't update

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using Redux, and I implemented a delete functionality in a list I have.
When the user deletes an item, I dispatch a `delete` call to the reducer, so I can remove the deleted item from the list.
But, the state won't update (the item is still in the array) but I can't figure out why.

This is how I dispatch the delete call:

```
const onDismiss = useCallback(g => {
  console.log(store.getState().reducer.goals);
  dispatch(deleteGoal(g.id));
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(store.getState().reducer.goals);
  }, 2000);
}, []);
```

this is deleteGoal action:

```
export const deleteGoal = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ActionType.deleteGoal,
            payload: id
        })
    }
}
```

This is the reducer:

```
case ActionType.deleteGoal:
    return {
        ...state,
        goals: state.goals.filter((goal: any) => goal.id !== action.id)
    }
```

This is the initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    goals: <any>[],
}
```

Comment: Simple. Change from ... !== action.id to !== action.payload.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at your reducer

```js
goals: state.goals.filter((goal: any) => goal.id !== action.id)
```

It should be `action.payload` instead

```js
goals: state.goals.filter((goal: any) => goal.id !== action.payload)
```

Whether it is `action.xx`, it is depending on what you dispatch in your `action`

```js
dispatch({
            type: ActionType.deleteGoal,
            payload: id
        })
```

Since you stored your `id` in `payload`, hence in your reducer you will need `action.payload`

Answer (score 1):

change `action.id` to `action.payload`

```
case ActionType.deleteGoal:
    return {
        ...state,
        goals: state.goals.filter((goal: any) => goal.id !== action.payload)
    }
```